# Jquery mobile checkboxes text turns to blue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using this piece of code, using jquery mobile

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

        <center><b> Platforms </b></center>

        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cbs" value = 28000000  onclick = check_cb() checked />
        <label for="cbs">28000000 Android</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cbi" value = 53000000 onclick = check_cb() />
        <label for="cbi">53000000 iPhone</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cbb" value = 36000000 onclick = check_cb() />
        <label for="cbb">36000000 BlackBerry</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cba" value = 11000000 onclick = check_cb() />
        <label for="cba">11000000 All Others</label>

        </fieldset> 

</div>
```

My checkboxes text turns to blue like as a link

Comment: `<center>`, `<b>` ??? Quotes and no quotes??? mmm...

Comment: If I paste that into JSFiddle, it doesn't turn blue. So there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: Use firebug to inspect the elements' CSS properties. Something in the chain will be setting th text colour.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's possibly your theme?
Check out jquery mobile Themeroller: http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php